# How to modify WP walker to get custom dropdown?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wp-nav-walker

im trying to make non standart main navigation menu and stuck with submenu items, according to most tutorials and wordpress guides walker class works with simple menu types like:

```
<ul>
 <li><a>Menu Item</a></li>
 <li><a>Menu Item</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a>Submenu Item</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Which is not suitable for my menu structure:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">
            <i class="nav-icons home_icon"></i>
            <p>Home</p>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="nav-icons catalog_icon"></i>
            <p>Catalog</p>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item">Catalog 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item">Catalog 2</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Im know that walker class forms menu with 4 functions (start_lvl, start_el, end_el, end_lvl) but is there any tutorial or any other info on how to make something simillar, or maybe someone could provide code sample to achieve result that im need? My menu will contain only 1 submenu level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This for the Bootstrap nav menu walker class,

```
if (!class_exists('BootstrapBasicMyWalkerNavMenu')) {
class BootstrapBasicMyWalkerNavMenu extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{


    //Overwrite display_element function to add has_children attribute. Not needed in >= Wordpress 3.4
    /**
     * @link https://gist.github.com/duanecilliers/1817371 copy from this url
     */
    function display_element($element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth = 0, $args, &$output)
    {
        if (!$element)
            return;
        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];

        //display this element
        if (is_array($args[0]))
            $args[0]['has_children'] = !empty($children_elements[$element->$id_field]);
        else if (is_object($args[0]))
            $args[0]->has_children = !empty($children_elements[$element->$id_field]);
        $cb_args = array_merge(array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
        call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'start_el'), $cb_args);

        $id = $element->$id_field;

        // descend only when the depth is right and there are childrens for this element
        if (($max_depth == 0 || $max_depth > $depth + 1) && isset($children_elements[$id])) {

            foreach ($children_elements[$id] as $child) {

                if (!isset($newlevel)) {
                    $newlevel = true;
                    //start the child delimiter
                    $cb_args = array_merge(array(&$output, $depth), $args);
                    call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'start_lvl'), $cb_args);
                }
                $this->display_element($child, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth + 1, $args, $output);
            }
            unset($children_elements[$id]);
        }

        if (isset($newlevel) && $newlevel) {
            //end the child delimiter
            $cb_args = array_merge(array(&$output, $depth), $args);
            call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_lvl'), $cb_args);
        }

        //end this element
        $cb_args = array_merge(array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
        call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_el'), $cb_args);
    }// display_element


    /**
     * @link https://gist.github.com/duanecilliers/1817371 copy from this url
     */
    public function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) 
    {
        if ((is_object($item) && $item->title == null) || (!is_object($item))) {
            return ;
        }

        $indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';

        $li_attributes = '';
        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        //Add class and attribute to LI element that contains a submenu UL.
        if (is_object($args) && $args->has_children) {
            //$classes[] = 'dropdown';
            $li_attributes .= ' data-dropdown="dropdown"';
        }
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        //If we are on the current page, add the active class to that menu item.
        $classes[] = ($item->current) ? 'active' : '';

        //Make sure you still add all of the WordPress classes.
        $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item, $args));
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"';

        $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args);
        $id = strlen($id) ? ' id="' . esc_attr($id) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . $li_attributes . '>';

        //Add attributes to link element.
        $attributes = !empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .=!empty($item->target) ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .=!empty($item->xfn) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr($item->xfn) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .=!empty($item->url) ? ' href="' . esc_attr($item->url) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= (is_object($args) && $args->has_children) ? ' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"' : '';

        $item_output = (is_object($args)) ? $args->before : '';
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        $item_output .= (is_object($args) ? $args->link_before : '') . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . (is_object($args) ? $args->link_after : '');
        $item_output .= (is_object($args) && $args->has_children) ? ' <span class="caret"></span> ' : '';
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= (is_object($args) ? $args->after : '');

        $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
    }// start_el


    public function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) 
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu dropdown-menu\">\n";
    }


}
}
```

How to use this,

```
 <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'your-menu-location', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav', 'walker' => new BootstrapBasicMyWalkerNavMenu())); ?>
```

Hope this will helps you.

For more information,

- [Understanding the Walker Class](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-walker-class--wp-25401)
- [WP Bootstrap Navwalker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker)
- [Custom Nav Menu Walker Function](http://shinraholdings.com/62/custom-nav-menu-walker-function/)

Comment: Thanks, it helped, im read all info that was needed to accomplish mission, im added some small modifications and now menu looks and works like they should by template design.